# Getting data from server using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my UI I have two tabs Albums and Tracks where each of this tabs shows some list of records depending on which one you click.

My question is, what is the best way to retrieve the data from server using Angular.JS, for the moment what I do is, once the page is loaded I call URL: channels/1 which response the channel obj with the data related to channel and   a sub arr of object of all albums and another sub array of objects of all tracks within this call. Would it be better if I call Albums and Tracks seperatly once I click the tab for ex Albums retrieve only albums for that channel as I already have the API channels/:channel_id/albums and for tracks channels/:channel_id/albums/5/tracks

What is the best practice in Angular to receive the data from server in this case??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 3 factories.   one for Channels and one for Albums, since tracks are an attribute of albums.

```
app.factory('Channels', [function(){
  return {
    get: function(){
       return arrayOfAlbums;
    }
  };
}]);

app.factory('Channel', [function(){
  return {
    getAlbums: function(){
       return arrayOfAssociatedAlbums;
    }
  };
}]);

app.factory('Album', [function(){
  return {
    getName: function(){
       return albumName;
    },
    getTracks: function{
       return arrayOfTracks;
    }
  };
}]);
```

Inside each function you create requests for your APIs.  Inside of these factories you will have many different functions to get aspects of each of the items. What I have above is real minimalistic

Comment: Should I make a call each time I click on the tabs, Album and Tracks, or load them once the page is loaded, inside Channel object as sub array of objects and use those data to tab Album and Tracks? or make a a call each time let say Album is clicked and make request to: channel/1/albums

Comment: If i load all at once, wouldnt it be problem at first let say I have 1000 tracks on that channel and 1000 albums, wouldnt it be better to call them seperatly?

Comment: You don't have to load them all at once.  You can create functions in the model factories to load only x at a time.  that way you only keep what you need.